# How to loop over the div to extract the sentence in the paragraph from a webpage?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp

I am practicing web scraping to extract comments (which is highlighted by red line) from a post in reddit using BeautifulSoup.
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXwjL.png)
Initially when I ran

```
for a in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'py-0 xs:ml-xs inline-block max-w-full'}):
  print(a.find('p').text)
```

it runs without error but no outputs were shown. Then I tried

```
every_review = soup.findAll('shreddit-comment-tree', {'id':'comment-tree'})
for rev in every_review.find('div', {'class':'md pl-[28px] xs:pl-xl text-14'}):
  for d in rev.find('div', {'id':'-post-rtjson-content'}):
    print(d.find('p').text)
```

It started to show error as below:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Does any professional have any idea how to solve this issue? And I wonder why it showed no output on my first run?

The output should be a list containing all sentences like *`[sent1, sent2, sent3...]`*

Comment: findAll returns a list, try replacing `soup.findAll` in your first line with `soup.find` (this should work since there is only one shreddit-comment-tree in your HTML).  If there are multiple shreddit-comment-trees, you will need to put another for loop in to iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, `findAll` returns a `ResultSet` [which is like a list of elements] rather than a single element [as `find` might return], so you cannot apply `.find` to *your* `every_review`. Try it in a `for` loop, like

```py
for every_review in soup.findAll('shreddit-comment-tree', {'id':'comment-tree'}):
  for rev in every_review.findAll('div', {'class':'md pl-[28px] xs:pl-xl text-14'}):
    for d in rev.findAll('div', {'id':'-post-rtjson-content'}):
      print(d.p.text if d.p else '!EMPTY -post-rtjson-content!') ## JUST IN CASE
```